# AuthenticationFailed raised after successfully getting Access Taken with OpenId Connect

Tags: oauth-2.0, asp.net-core, openid, access-token

I am currently working on an Asp.Net Core project that uses OpenId to handle user authentication to their Office 365 environment. Here is how I setup my OpenId/Cookies:

```
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions()
        {
            AuthenticationScheme = "Cookies",
            AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
            AutomaticChallenge = true,
            AccessDeniedPath = new PathString("/Home/Forbidden"),
            CookieSecure = CookieSecurePolicy.SameAsRequest,

            // The default setting for cookie expiration is 14 days. SlidingExpiration is set to true by default
            ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(1),
            SlidingExpiration = true
        });

        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectOptions()
        {
            AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
            AutomaticChallenge = true,
            ClientId = Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings").GetValue<string>("ClientId"),
            Authority = Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings").GetValue<string>("AzureADAuthority"),
            CallbackPath = "/Dashboard",
            PostLogoutRedirectUri = Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings").GetValue<string>("LogoutAuthority"),
            SignInScheme = "Cookies",
            TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters { ValidateIssuer = false },
            Events = new LhAuthenticationEvents(settings.Value),
            SaveTokens = true,
            ResponseType = "code id_token"

        });
```

In my LhAuthentificationEvents, I use AuthorizationCodeReceived to successfully retrieve the user's access token, but for some reason, after exiting AuthorizationCodeReceived, AuthenticationFailed gets called.

```
    public override Task AuthenticationFailed(AuthenticationFailedContext context)
    {
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }
```

Context contains the following exception:

Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized).

With the following stacktrace:

at System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler.d__21.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler.d__19.MoveNext()

Comment: Enable log and check actual problem.

Comment: Side note: your CallbackPath is probobly wrong. It shouldn't refer to another endpoint in your app, it should be a unique path handled by the middleware itself.